# How to add nodes in VSTS Scrum backlog to group sprints?

Tags: azure-devops, scrum, backlog

In VSTS Scrum project, in the backlog, we have sprints organized in parent nodes "Past", "Current", "Future". But can we add others parent nodes (as Releases or milestones) to group sprints, to have this :

```
> Release v1
  Sprint 1
  Sprint 2
> Release v2
  Sprint 3
  Sprint 4
```

I tried to add area "Release V1" and Release V2", but they doesn't appear in backlog ?

Otherswise, is there a way to represent milestones without using tags in each features ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add nodes to gourp sprints.

But for now, backlog board can only show the parents inerations (such as `Release V1`) or the children inerations (such as `Sprint 1` and `Sprint 2`). **It can not show both parents inerations and children inerations at the same time**.

I posted an user voice [Enable to show both parent/child Inerations for Backlog board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32929048-enable-to-show-both-parent-child-inerations-for-ba), you can vote and follow up.

Comment: But I can see also the parents iterations "Past", "Current" and "Future".

Comment: "Past", "Current" and "Future" are not parents inerations. They aim to separate inerations based the inerations start time the end time. You can also double check in the work tab (https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_work), "Past", "Current" and "Future" are not show as inerations (as the example https://imgur.com/a/xsefl).